# If $6x + 5\equiv 7\pmod n$ has a solution, show that one of $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n - 1$ is also a solution

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $u$ be a solution to $6x + 5\equiv 7\pmod n$ so that $6u + 5\equiv 7\pmod n$. So, there must be some $v$ such that $u \equiv v \pmod n.$

Then, $u \equiv v \pmod n \rightarrow 6u \equiv 6v \pmod n \rightarrow 6u+5 \equiv 6v+5 \pmod n \rightarrow 7 \equiv 6v+5 \pmod n.$ So, $v$ is another solution.

Since $v = nq + r$ where $r = 1, 2, 3, \ldots, n - 1,$ then $[v]$ is one of $[1], [2], [3], \ldots, [n -1].$

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that $0$ is not a solution, because $5$ is not congruent to $7$ for any modulus $n\ge 2$. You must say this to complete the proof.

Assuming that, what you wrote is correct, but unnecessarily long. You don't need $v$ at all.

Just write $u=nq+r$ and then $[u]$ is one of $[1]$, $[2]$,...,$[n-1]$.

Comment: Suppose $[u] = [k].$ Does $u$ equal more than one element of $[k]$? Does the problem actually mean "if $u$ is a solution, then it has the value among $1, 2, 3,\ldots, n$"? In other words, the problem is not asking for two different solutions?